# Null-terminate string: Use '\0' or just 0?

Tags: c++, c, null-terminated

If I need to null-terminate a String, should I rather use `\0` or is a simple `0` also enough?

Is there any difference between using

```
char a[5];
a[0] = 0;
```

and

```
char a[5];
a[0] = '\0';
```

Or is `\0` just preferred to make it clear that I'm null-terminating here, but for the compiler it is the same?

Comment: For C++, just use `std::string` and forget about C strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Use '\0' or just 0?

There is no difference in value.
In C, there is no difference in type: both are `int`.
In C++ they have different types: `char` and `int`.  So the edge goes to `'\0'` as there is no type conversion involved.

Different style guides promote one over the other. `'\0'` for clarity. `0` for lack of clutter.

**Right answer:** Use the style based on your group's coding standards/guidelines.  If you group does not have such guideline, make one.  Better to use one than have divergent styles.

Answer (score 15):

`'\0'` is an [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for an [octal literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)  with the value of 0.  So there is no difference between them

Side note: if you are dealing with strings than you should use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 8):

`'\0'` is exactly the same as `0` despite of the type. `'\0'` is just a representation as a `char` literal. The type `char` can be initialized from plain `int` literals though.

So it's actually impossible to tell what's better, just keep in mind to use it consistently in your code.

Comment: Detail: In C, `'\0'` is more properly called a _character constant_.  Only literals C specifies are _string literal_ and _compound literal_.

Comment: Note: In C, character constants like `'\0'` are of type `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 6):

Both will generate the same machine code, as `0` will be converted to the character value `0`, and `'\0'` is just another way of writing the character value `0`. The latter is clearly a character, so it will show that you didn't accidentally mean to write `'0'` instead, but other than that, it's exactly the same thing in the end.

Comment: Note: In C, character constants like `'\0'` are of type `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing. Look at the ascii table.

It's better from my point of view to use '\0' because you explicity say that the end of string.

That help when you read your code (like using NULL for pointer instead of 0).

Comment: _" Look at the ascii table."_ What about EBCDIC character tables? Would that still be true?